# How do cross products and bivectors transform?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, cross-product, exterior-algebra

Let $V$ a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.
As far as I understand, a bivector is an antisymmetric second rank tensor, thus an element of $V\otimes V$.

Let $\{\underline{e_i}\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{\underline{e'_i}\}_{i=1}^n$ be two basis sets for $V$ such that (please note that I'm using Einstein's convention):
\begin{equation}
\underline{e_i}=\lambda_i^j\underline{e_j'} \quad i=1,2...n
\end{equation}
The wedge product of two vectors of $V$ is a bivector so in terms of components it should transform like a second order contravariant tensor (an element of $V\otimes V$).

Let $\underline{a}=a^i\underline{e_i}, \underline{b}=b^i\underline{e_i}$ two vectors in $V$ and $\{e^i\}_{i=1}^n$, $\{e'^i\}_{i=1}^n$  be the dual bases corresponding to the basis above, so we have:
\begin{equation}
e^i=\mu_j^ie'^j \quad i=1,2...n \quad\text{with}\quad \lambda_a^b\mu_b^c=\delta_a^c
\end{equation}
Then, we can see that:

\begin{equation}
(\underline{a}\wedge\underline{b})^{ij}=\underline{a}\wedge\underline{b}(e^i, e^j)=\underline{a}\wedge\underline{b}(\mu_a^ie'^a, \mu_b^je'^b)=\mu_a^i\mu_b^j\thinspace\underline{a}\wedge\underline{b}(e'^a,e'^b)=\mu_a^i\mu_b^j(\underline{a}\wedge\underline{b})'^{ab}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Being an antisymmetric second rank tensor, it has only $3$ independent components, so considering $V=\mathbb{R}^3$, each bivector corresponds to a vector of $V$. Introducing Levi-Civita simbol, we can define this vector by its components with respect to a basis:

\begin{equation}
\underline{a}\times\underline{b}=\epsilon_{ijk}a^jb^k\underline{e_i}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

This kind of object is also referred to as *pseudovector* or *axial vector*. How does $(2)$ when we change the basis and how can we we write an equation analogous to $(1)$?

In simple words I am asking if the cross product in equation $(2)$ "transforms with two matrices", like equation $(1)$.

Please, forgive my lack of rigor, I'm quite new to tensor calculus and I am a physics students as well.